# How to fill a column with formula till a row with data

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a table as shown in figure.

[image]

It is about the transaction of a few items with date, qty and rate. Column E calculates the total cost filling the column automatically as new entry is typed.

Column F sums up the item quantity and column G calculates the current rate of the item for each row. What I want is that column also gets filled with a single formula in cells F3 and G3, as in the case of column E. Can it be done? Can an array formula do the trick?

Regards,
Pravin Kumar.

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet. Without that, the volunteer contributors here would need to start a new sheet of their own and manually enter all of your data before they could even start to solve the issue; and that will be a deterrent. Help us help you by giving us a starting point. Consider sharing the link.

Comment: I hope that the question is generic and adding a sheet to the question does not add extra clarity. However, I will add a sheet by retyping the values again. I had accidentally erased the temporary sheet!

Comment: The sheet will not add clarity; it will give the volunteer contributors here a starting point to work. When writing any formula, it should be tested against real data in real ranges. Everyone's ranges are different. And no developer, no matter how smart, carries around every formula in our heads. We have to type it out and make sure it works in each case. If you do recreate the link and share the test spreadsheet, please comment again so that I'll receive an alert, and I will take another look.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJyEOu3Vmx7lFTzlJScNVUC3HWi1rRWJEbBzprrhlYo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the link to a quickly set up sheet with random figures. A new row added (row no 11) fills up column E. This is what I wanted to achieve for columns F & G.
Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJyEOu3Vmx7lFTzlJScNVUC3HWi1rRWJEbBzprrhlYo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The link denies access to everyone but yourself. Please set the permission on the link to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" (or at least "Anyone with the link..." and "View").

Answer (score 1):

it's called resetting running total...

use in F3:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))))*(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))))), 
 INDIRECT("C3:C"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))), 0)), ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))))^0))
```

and use in G3:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))))>=ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))))*(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))))), 
 INDIRECT("D3:D"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))), 0)), ROW(
 INDIRECT("B3:B"&MAX(ROW(B3:B)*(B3:B<>""))))^0)/FILTER(F3:F, F3:F<>""))
```